# Array values all stay at 0.0 after user input

Tags: java, arrays

Basically I have code that allows the user to create an array but for some reason the values stay at 0.0

Here is the code:

```js
/**  
 * @author Brian 
 * @version 21 Oct 2017 
 */
/**
 * Example of program execution:
 * Using arrays, and finding the average, max and sum.
 * The array with 4 elements is [4.5, 2.0, 1.2, 3.3]
 * The sum of [4.5, 2.0, 1.2, 3.3] is 11.00 
 * The Average of [4.5, 2.0, 1.2, 3.3] is 2.75 
 * The minimum of [4.5, 2.0, 1.2, 3.3] is 1.20 
 * How many numbers: 3
 * Enter lower and upper range limits: 1 100
 * Enter number 0: 2
 * Enter number 1: 2
 * Enter number 2: 2
 * The sum of [0.0, 0.0, 0.0] is 0.00  
 * The Average of [0.0, 0.0, 0.0] is 0.00  
 * The minimum of [0.0, 0.0, 0.0] is 0.00  
 * After fill with 1.2, the array is [1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2] 
 */
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EngArray {
  /**
   * Test the array methods
   * @param args the command line arguments
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Using arrays, and finding the average, max and sum.");
    // a) Declare and initialise an array to hold the real data values 2.3, 4.6, 3.0 and 1.1. 
    double[] array1 = {
      4.5,
      2.0,
      1.2,
      3.3
    };
    // b) Using the provided toString( ) method display the array values 
    // Example code to test method toString( ) below, replace test array with the above array name.
    String array1Str = toString(array1);
    System.out.println("The array with 4 elements is " + array1Str);
    // c) Invoke calcSum and display the numbers and the sum 
    System.out.printf("The sum of %s is %.2f ", array1Str, calcSum(array1));
    // d) Invoke calcAvg and display the numbers and their average 
    System.out.printf("\nThe Average of %s is %.2f ", array1Str, calcAvg(array1));
    // e) Invoke findMin and display the minimum
    System.out.printf("\nThe minimum of %s is %.2f ", array1Str, findMin(array1));
    // g) Invoke makeArray and then display the sum, average and minimum of new array
    double[] madeArray = makeArray();
    String madeArrayStr = toString(madeArray);
    System.out.printf("The sum of %s is %.2f ", madeArrayStr, calcSum(madeArray));
    System.out.printf(" \nThe Average of %s is %.2f ", madeArrayStr, calcAvg(madeArray));
    System.out.printf(" \nThe minimum of %s is %.2f ", madeArrayStr, findMin(madeArray));
    // h) Invoke fill to set a new array of 6 elements to 1.2 and then display modified array
    double[] arrayofsix = {
      3.4,
      5.1,
      9.8,
      2.2,
      4.0,
      7.6
    };
    fill(arrayofsix, 1.2);
    String arrayofsixStr = toString(arrayofsix);
    System.out.printf(" \nAfter fill with %s, the array is %s ", "1.2", arrayofsixStr);
  }
  public static double calcSum(double[] array) {
    double[] array1;
    double sum = 0;
    for (int counter = 0; counter < array.length; counter++)
      sum += array[counter];

    return sum;

  }

  public static double calcAvg(double[] array) {
    double Avg = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    for (int counter = 0; counter < array.length; counter++)
      sum += array[counter];
    Avg = sum / array.length;

    return Avg;
  }

  public static double findMin(double[] array) {
    double Min = array[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (array[i] < Min) {
        Min = array[i];
      }
    }
    return Min;
  }

  /**
   * Returns a string representation of the array i.e. a comma separated list 
   * of elements within [ ].  Similar to java.util.Arrays.toString(double[] a) method.
   * Each array element will be displayed by String.valueOf(double).
   * @param array  the array whose string representation is required
   * @return a string representation of array
   */
  public static String toString(double[] array) {
    String arrayStr = "[";

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (i > 0) // Insert comma separator after first one
        arrayStr += ", ";
      arrayStr += String.valueOf(array[i]);
    }
    arrayStr += "]";
    return arrayStr;
  }

  /**
   * Input a set of elements and store in the created array. The user specifies
   * the size of the array, and enters the elements.
   * @return the created array
   */
  public static double[] makeArray() // Part f)
  {
    final String format = "%.2f";
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("\nHow many numbers: ");
    int numNumbers = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter lower and upper range limits: ");
    double lower = input.nextDouble();
    double upper = input.nextDouble();

    double[] numArray = new double[numNumbers];


    for (int i = 0; i < numNumbers; i++) {
      double number;
      System.out.printf("Enter number %d: ", i);
      number = input.nextDouble();

      while (number < lower || number > upper) {
        System.out.print("Please re-enter in range ");
        System.out.printf("[" + format + " to " + format + "]: ", lower, upper);
        number = input.nextDouble();
      }
    }
    return numArray;


  }
  /**
   *  initialise each element of the array to the given value.
   */
  public static void fill(double[] array, double value) {
    double[] array6 = new double[6];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
      array[i] = value;
  }
}
```

I have a feeling that the only part of code that would affect this is here however:

```js
public static double[] makeArray() // Part f)
{
  final String format = "%.2f";
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.print("\nHow many numbers: ");
  int numNumbers = input.nextInt();

  System.out.print("Enter lower and upper range limits: ");
  double lower = input.nextDouble();
  double upper = input.nextDouble();

  double[] numArray = new double[numNumbers];


  for (int i = 0; i < numNumbers; i++) {
    double number;
    System.out.printf("Enter number %d: ", i);
    number = input.nextDouble();

    while (number < lower || number > upper) {
      System.out.print("Please re-enter in range ");
      System.out.printf("[" + format + " to " + format + "]: ", lower, upper);
      number = input.nextDouble();
    }
  }
  return numArray;


}
```

Comment: Well, is there anywhere in that method where you initialize the elements of numArray, i.e. have numArray[someIndex] = someValue? I don't see any.

Comment: Statements in your question such as, "I have searched everywhere..." and "sorry if this is too long..." provide no useful information that helps anyone understand your code, your problem, or your question. In the future, instead of this useless information, put in more effort explaining your code and your problem as well as posting less code that is not relevant to your problem or necessary to allow the code to compile and run.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public static double[] makeArray() // Part f)
{
  final String format = "%.2f";
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.print("\nHow many numbers: ");
  int numNumbers = input.nextInt();

  System.out.print("Enter lower and upper range limits: ");
  double lower = input.nextDouble();
  double upper = input.nextDouble();

  double[] numArray = new double[numNumbers];


  for (int i = 0; i < numNumbers; i++) {
    double number;
    System.out.printf("Enter number %d: ", i);
    number = input.nextDouble();

    while (number < lower || number > upper) {
      System.out.print("Please re-enter in range ");
      System.out.printf("[" + format + " to " + format + "]: ", lower, upper);
      number = input.nextDouble();
    }
    // YOU FORGOT TO ASSIGN THE GENERATED NUMBER TO ARRAY
    numArray[i] = number;
  }
  return numArray;


}
```

Comment: Code dump answers are low quality answers and are not helpful to future visitors. Instead focus on posting a decent explanation.